# Why is Android Studio scrolling code editor to last cursor position?

Tags: android, android-studio, editor

When I open a Java file in Android Studio, the code editor automatically jumps to the last position my cursor was at when I closed the file.  Is there a way to disable this 'feature'?  I just simply want to go to the top of the file when I open a file...

Answer (score 1):

It's Alt + Ctrl + Right/Left arrow.

You can change these shortcuts under:
File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Keymap > Main menu > Navigate > Back/Forward.